# SQL - IF statement around AND

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement

I'm trying to create a query that will only add AND clauses where certain conditions are met.

This is what I'm after:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id
  name
  active
FROM team
WHERE id = 1234
IF team.active = 'y'
  AND team.id IN
    {
       query
    }
ELSEIF team.active = 'n'
  AND team.id IN
    {
      query
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in SQL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    id
    name
    active
    FROM team
 WHERE id = 1234
   AND (team.active = 'y'
     AND team.id IN
        {
          query
        }) 
   OR
    (team.active = 'n'
     AND team.id IN
      {
        query
      })
```

You use the AND and OR connectives to create the logic.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Marked this as answer as you beat the other guy by a minute.

Answer (score 3):

You can use boolean logic like so

```
SELECT ...
FROM team
WHERE id = 1234
    AND (
        (team.active = 'y' AND team.id IN query)
        OR
        (team.active = 'n' AND team.id IN query)
    )
```

Did I miss the difference in the two branches?

Comment: I think `query` is meant to be different for each branch. That's were the difference lies.

Answer (score -1):

You can use decode statement for achieving the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id
  name
  active
FROM team
WHERE id = 1234 and
team.id in (
decode (team.active,'y',(query),'n',(query))
```

you can also use case statment

Comment: It's a SQL Server question, not Oracle